# cell array of strings to matlab structure

Tags: matlab, cells, array

I need to create a matlab structure as such `ds=struct('name',{{'my_name_is'},{'matlab_thining_hair'}})` which stores as a 1x2 structure array with a field name. A call to `ds.name` generates the output:

```
ds.name
ans = 'my_name_is'
ans = 'matlab_thining_hair'
```

Please note the single quotes in the output. They are important. That said, I need to create the above mentioned structure using the following variable: `X = [1x46 char] [1x47 char]` i.e., 1x2 cell, which I believe is actually a cell array of strings. Among other things, I've tried the following:

```
Y = cell2struct(X, 'name', 1)'
```

which results in a 1x2 structure array with fields name, however a call to Y generates the output:

```
Y.name
ans = my_name_is
ans = matlab_thining_hair
```

Note that the single quotes in the output are missing, and albeit both Y and ds are 1x2 struct arrays with fields name, the field values are not formatted the same and the structures also vary in their bytes size. Essentially what I need is a struct with fields of cell arrays, where essentially each cell array consists of a unique char array. I am at a loss as how to format the field values as character arrays? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy in your example is that each element of your original example ds.name is a cell containing a char (e.g. {'my name is'}), whereas each element of X is a char (e.g. 'my name is'). If you change the type of each element of X from a char to a cell containing a char then you should get the behaviour you are looking for.

This is shown in the example below.

> X2={{'my_name_is'},{'matlab_thinning_hair'}};
>
> Y = cell2struct(X2, 'name', 1);
>
> Y.name
>
> ans =
>
> 'my_name_is'
>
> ans =
>
> 'matlab_thinning_hair'

You could achieve this for your variable X by indexing through the elements and carrying out:

> X2{1}={X{1}};
>
> X2{2}={X{2}}

The matlab help [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html) is quite helpful on this topic.